# What are the advantages and disadvantages of tower and rack servers

Tags: linux, hosting, rack

I would like to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of tower servers on rack-mounted servers and vice versa.

In terms of performance, safety, cooling system, maintenance...

I want to know which option to choose for my company which wants to host its own website and have its own mail server?

Comment: A bigger difference is probably between tower or rack versus cloud-hosted virtual, which you should also consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rack server is designed to be positioned in a bay, which enables you to stack various devices on top of each other in a large tower. The bay will accommodate all of the hardware devices the company needs to function, including the server, storage devices, and security and network appliances.

Racks servers needs a [cabinet](https://www.amazon.com/server-rack-cabinet/s?k=server%20rack%20cabinet).

other criteria (like cooling,performance) vary by brand and model.

You can read [this article](http://techgenix.com/tower-vs-rack-vs-blade-servers/) for more details.